# how to convert json array like this to view laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

i try to use decode but always have error
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

> `
> {"status":{"timestamp":"2020-11-26T12:19:43.442Z","error_code":0,"error_message":null,"elapsed":12,"credit_count":1,"notice":null,"total_count":3841},"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","slug":"bitcoin","num_market_pairs":9535,"date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z","tags":["mineable","pow","sha-256","store-of-value","state-channels"],"max_supply":21000000,"circulating_supply":18554631,"total_supply":18554631,"platform":null,"cmc_rank":1,"last_updated":"2020-11-26T12:18:02.000Z","quote":{"USD":{"price":17247.70801162772,"volume_24h":59005040595.46997,"percent_change_1h":0.03819689,"percent_change_24h":-10.66818958,"percent_change_7d":-2.58426346,"market_cap":320024857751.4961,"last_updated":"2020-11-26T12:18:02.000Z"}}},{"id":1027,"name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH","slug":"ethereum","num_market_pairs":5769,"date_added":"2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z","tags":["mineable","pow","smart-contracts"],"max_supply":null,"circulating_supply":113584879.624,"total_supply":113584879.624,"platform":null,"cmc_rank":2,"last_updated":"2020-11-26T12:18:02.000Z","quote":{"USD":{"price":515.9676158574783,"volume_24h":29731138661.457035,"percent_change_1h":1.4170852,"percent_change_24h":-14.25703562,"percent_change_7d":9.42588329,"market_cap":58606119537.05395,"last_updated":"2020-11-26T12:18:02.000Z"}}},{"id":52,"name":"XRP","symbol":"XRP","slug":"xrp","num_market_pairs":669,"date_added":"2013-08-04T00:00:00.000Z","tags":["medium-of-exchange","enterprise-solutions","binance-chain"],"max_supply":100000000000,"circulating_supply":45348221180,"total_supply":99990853796,"platform":null,"cmc_rank":3,"last_updated":"2020-11-26T12:19:02.000Z","quote":{"USD":{"price":0.54209162288765,"volume_24h":23930358898.866245,"percent_change_1h":2.29364957,"percent_change_24h":-22.25604323,"percent_change_7d":87.81226505,"market_cap":24582890814.5343,"last_updated":"2020-11-26T12:19:02.000Z"}}}]}

`

Comment: What is the shape of data you are trying to decode? Post a sample here if you can to understand  - of data you are trying to decode.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “JSON array”. You either have actual JSON, in string form - but then there would be no reason that you would get this error when calling json_decode - or you don’t. Don’t just show us such a piece of data, that doesn’t help us determine what your actual issue is - show us a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: i try to get all information from CoinMarket and i do it
i use CoinMarketCapApi::all_cryptos(); that show all data like example up ..
trying to convert the data to view html like ul li .. i can't can u help me

Comment: Please share your code that you have tried

Comment: {"id":1,"name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","slug":"bitcoin","num_market_pairs":9535,"date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z","tags":["mineable","pow","sha-256","store-of-value","state-channels"],"max_supply":21000000,"circulating_supply":18554631,"total_supply":18554631,"platform":null,"cmc_rank":1,"last_updated":"2020-11-26T12:18:02.000Z","quote":{"USD":{"price":17247.70801162772,"volume_24h":59005040595.46997,"percent_change_1h":0.03819689,"percent_change_24h":-10.66818958,"percent_change_7d":-2.58426346,"market_cap":320024857751.4961,"last_updated":"2020-11-26T12:18:02.000Z"}}}

Comment: need to get id or name in ul li

Comment: @Saleh the data you have posted in comment doesn't give any error with json_decode. Need to check the code where you are receiving the data and then trying to do json_decode

Answer (score 0):

First do json_encode() and then do json_decode(), see what you are getting.

Comment: What's the use? If the data is already in array format or object format why is it needed to first encode as json and then decode again?

Answer (score 0):

You need just to put second parameter in method `json_decode` as `true`

like: `json_decode($json, true);`